# c#: google drive : google apis.services are you missing an assembly or reference

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

i am trying to use google.drive for .net using the quickstart example. i have installed dlls via nuget, but am receiving the following error that i am missing a reference or assembly for google.apis.service. any help would be appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Services;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         String CLIENT_ID = "some_id";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "some_secret";

            // Register the authenticator and create the service
            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                Authenticator = auth
            });

            File body = new File();
            body.Title = "My document";
            body.Description = "A test document";
            body.MimeType = "text/plain";

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
            request.Upload();

            File file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
        {
            // Get the auth URL:
            IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue() });
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
            Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

            // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
            Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
            Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
            string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't put the secret stuff in the open!

Comment: At what point do you get the exception? Or is it during compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to run our Drive.Sample from our samples repository - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2FDrive.Sample. You can see a working implementation there (it also includes media upload and download code).
2. Try to start over again and install the following two packages (I'm not sure if you already  did so):
   Google.Apis.Drive.v2 - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/
   Google.Apis.Authetnication - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Authentication

UPDATE (January 22nd 2014):

We reimplemented the OAuth 2.0 library and removed the dependency in DotNetOpenAuth several months ago. 
You can read more about it in the [announcements blog](http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/). Search specifically for the 1.6.0-beta release.

You should also take a look in our OAuth 2.0 page - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2.

Another good reference is our samples repository. All the samples had been upgraded to use the new Google.Apis.Auth package.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but there seems to be a problem with all three links provided here. Downloading the zip is blocked due to an ssl cert error it seems (Cannot connect to the real samples.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com

Something is currently interfering with your secure connection to samples.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com.)

Comment: As for Nuget both of those package names have been changed, I was able to use the command "get-package -listavailable google.apis" to look through the available packages to find it was simply changed to "Google.Apis.Drive", which is documented nowhere as far as I can tell.

As for the authentication when I search available packages the name column is character limited so I get back "Google.Apis.Authentication.... " as the package name. So I am left some characters short of being able to find out what the new package name is! Is there a way I can find out what they have changed the pkg name to?

Comment: @peleyal "All the samples had been upgraded to use the new Google.Apis.Auth package".  May I know where are these located?  I have just downloaded the latest DrEdit from GitHub and it is still using the old Google.Apis.Authentication namespaces.

Comment: Our samples repository - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples