# C# Google Drive: Google.Apis.Services is missing

Tags: google-drive-api

This question is a repeat of [c#: google drive : google apis.services are you missing an assembly or reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897662/c-google-drive-google-apis-services-are-you-missing-an-assembly-or-reference) but the accepted answer from that post links to outdated information.

I am trying to follow the quickstart guide available here: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs but for step 2 the client library is not available as a zip anymore but instead through NuGet. The package names needed have also changed which is not documented anywhere. The package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/ is now Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive instead of Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2.

I found that out from using "get-package -listavailable google.apis" to filter the available packages listed, however I cannot do the same to find out what the authentication package is now called because the character limit on the name column cuts off saying this:

Id                             Version              Description
--                             -------              -----------
Google.Apis.Authentication.... 1.2.4696.27633       Google APIs Client Library

I'm still assuming that answer for the previous post is correct and getting the authentication api will fix Google.Apis.Services missing but considering how outdated the available documentation is and how much has changed outside of page I may still have that problem afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that tutorial is out of date.  You should be using these.

```
pm> install-package google.apis -pre
pm> install-package google.apis.drive.v2 -pre
```

But that tutorial wont help you much becouse `NativeApplicationClient` has been depreciated.

This tutorial should get you started [GOOGLE DRIVE API C#](http://daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/?rel=nofollow)

Comment: Thanks for that, and forgive me if I've gone crazy but are the Google.Apis.* packages no longer listed? Those commands you gave me do not work and looking using "Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter google.apis" returns nothing anymore. The only difference between me looking for those packages this week and the last is that I updated NuGet (Because the -pre command was causing errors). Were those packages removed or am I going a little crazy?